# Coordinate jumping for p5js game Entities

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, p5.js

*Hi! This is my first question on StackOverflow!*

###### Background

I have been staring at this code for a day+ now, and am a bit stuck.

I am making a little game, using [p5js](https://p5js.org/). Its like Asteroids, but instead of the player (`Origin`) moving upon key press, entities (`Entity`) will move. This is an effort to somewhat clone Adam Saltsman's ([@adamatomic](https://twitter.com/adamatomic)) ["CAPSULE"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jkDp-sr87M&ab_channel=Seeric), as a personal project.

###### Issue

A Player can press left/right arrow keys and movement is correct.
A Player can press up/down arrow keys and movement is fine.

**After pressing up/down, and then going back to press left/right, the Entity jumps to a completely different coordinate.**

I know I'm doing something incorrect in my `Entity#update()` function, but perhaps my brain has glazed over a little bit. I've tried:

- assigning `this.x` based on location
- figuring out based on which quadrant the entity is currently in, to adjust/not adjust the coordinates

[Example of coordinate jumping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdq10.gif)

###### Code

A run-able code example can be seen/edited [here](https://editor.p5js.org/atkascha/sketches/38p8Fu5sY), using the p5js Web Editor. It is a bit  in places.

The `Entity#update` function:

```
  update(origin) {
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
      this.angle += 1;
      this.x = origin.x + this.distanceToOrigin * sin(this.angle);
      this.y = origin.y + this.distanceToOrigin * cos(this.angle);
      this._updateVector(origin);
    } else if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
      this.angle -= 1;
      this.x = origin.x + this.distanceToOrigin * sin(this.angle);
      this.y = origin.y + this.distanceToOrigin * cos(this.angle);
      this._updateVector(origin);
    }

    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
      this.y += 2;
      this._calculateAngle(origin);
    } else if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
      this.y -= 2;
      this._calculateAngle(origin);
    }
  }
```

###### Possible solutions?

I am not really leveraging vectors in this implementation, and instead just using points. They exist mainly for determining angles, but aren't actually leveraged. While it seems to (kind of) work, I am not opposed to altering this to vector based movement, if that would help resolve this issue. I think I could rewrite that *reasonably* quick.

Thank you!

Comment: I was able to get some advice from a Discord I am in.

- My presumption under "Possible solutions?" was correct and pursuing a more vector based approach would be more correct

- Flipping `sin`/`cos`

But the "tldr" of it all, is to leverage polar coordinates. 

I'm not the best at trigonometry (obviously), so it looks like a small rewrite is in order.

Comment: So is the intent to rotate clockwise and counterclockwise with the Left and Right arrows and then up and down with the Up and Down arrows?  As the code presented (and the p5.js Web Editor example) are coded as such, with the minor hiccup of the jumping.  Or is the intent that the Left and Right arrows are to simply make adjustments to the X coordinate?  (Oh, and if the intent is for Left/Right to rotate, the primary issue is that the Up/Down uses the atan rather than atan2 function to calculate the new angle.  The atan2 function takes into account the quadrant when calculating the angle...)

Comment: @Trentium Thank you for the reply.

The intent is is to have Entities rotate left, when the right arrow key is pressed, and vice versa. It simulates a "radar POV" of a ship/craft. It should, ideally, keep the same distance from the Origin.

Thank you for the note on atan2. While not entirely new to p5js, this sort of endeavor is definitely new, and I appreciate the insight/info.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the main issue you are running into is with the use of `atan` rather than `atan2`, the latter which takes into account the signs of (x,y) in order to return the angle in the appropriate quadrant.  This is why the vector is appearing to jump 90 or 180 degrees...

Additionally, seeing that you are making use of classes, I took the liberty of making some adjustments to the `Entity` class, driven primarily by simplifying the data structure and reducing mathematical redundancy.

- Class `Entity`, except for the `draw()` method, now just deals with the (x,y) coordinates of the vector itself.
- The `draw()` function is the only function that makes use of the `origin`.
- The (x,y) coordinates are stored as private variables within the `Entity` class, and as such, the setter methods for both `this.x` and `this.y` automatically update `this.vector`.  Thus, when method `update()` sets `this.y += 2`, the `set y()` method is automatically updating `this.vector`.  This even allows for callers to directly manipulate `x`, `y`, `radius`, or `length` of an instance of `Entity`, and the vector will automatically be updated...
- The vector properties of `radius` and `angle` are now calculated values based on the (x,y) coordinates, rather than being stored and constantly having to be kept in sync with (x,y).

The `debug()` function also needed tweaking, to accommodate the `Entity` class no longer mixing in the origin with (x,y)...

```
class Entity {
  
  #x;
  #y;
  
  constructor( id, x = null, y = null ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.vector = createVector();
    this.x = x || random( width );
    this.y = y || random( height );
    this.size = 10;
    this.locations = [];
    
  }

  update() {
    if ( keyIsDown( LEFT_ARROW ) ) {
      this.angle += 0.01;
    } else if ( keyIsDown( RIGHT_ARROW ) ) {
      this.angle -= 0.01;
    }

    if ( keyIsDown( UP_ARROW ) ) {
      this.y += 2;
    } else if ( keyIsDown( DOWN_ARROW ) ) {
      this.y -= 2;
    }

    this._storePastLocation();
  }

  get x() {
    return this.#x;
  }

  set x( x ) {
    this.#x = x;
    this.vector.set( this.#x, this.#y );
  }

  get y() {
    return this.#y;
  }

  set y( y ) {
    this.#y = y;
    this.vector.set( this.#x, this.#y );
  }

  get angle() {
    return atan2( this.y, this.x );
  }
  
  set angle( a ) {
    let r = this.radius;
    this.x = r * cos( a );
    this.y = r * sin( a );
  }
  
  get radius() {
    return sqrt( this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y );
  }
  
  set radius( r ) {
    let a = this.angle;
    this.x = r * cos( a );
    this.y = r * sin( a );
  }

  draw() {
    stroke("red");
    for ( let location of this.locations ) {
      rect( origin.x + location.x - this.size / 2, origin.y + location.y + this.size / 2, this.size );
    }
    rect( origin.x + this.x - this.size / 2, origin.y + this.y + this.size / 2, this.size );
  }

  _storePastLocation() {
    this.locations.push( { x: this.x, y: this.y } );
    if ( this.locations.length > 5 ) {
      this.locations.shift();
    }
  }

}
```

```
function debug({ ents, origin }) {
  stroke("grey");
  line(0, height / 2, width, height / 2);
  line(width / 2, 0, width / 2, height);

  for (let ent of ents) {
    stroke("black");
    //text(`v: ${parseInt(ent.vectorAngle)}°`, ent.x, ent.y - 15);
    //text(`a: ${parseInt(ent.angle)}°`, ent.x, ent.y);
    //text(`i: ${ent.id}`, ent.x, ent.y + 28);
    text(`x: ${parseInt(ent.x)}`, origin.x + ent.x, origin.y + ent.y + 40);
    text(`y: ${parseInt(ent.y)}`, origin.x + ent.x, origin.y + ent.y + 52);
    //text(`d: ${parseInt(ent.distanceToOrigin)}`, ent.x, ent.y - 30);
  }

  drawArrow(origin.baseVector, origin.vector, "red");
  for (let i = 0; i < ents.length; i++) {
    drawArrow(origin.baseVector, ents[i].vector, colors[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I will definitely copy this code and tinker with it. Thank you for such a verbose response, I definitely appreciate. It has been a fair bit of time since I've had to do any sort of trigonometry and "rusty" is an understatement. The code I wrote was an example, but I also appreciate the refactor advice. I will plug this in and work with it. Thank you again :)

Comment: That's another benefit of parting out the class into smaller functional methods, as in this case it makes the trigonometry clearer...  P.S.  Well written first question!